# Sending requests with LocalDate type parameters

Tags: java, spring, date, spring-boot, localdate

I wanted to send request like this:

- http://localhost:8080/reports/daily?start_date=2018-03-22&end_date=2018-03-24

I have an error:

> "2018-05-31 15:40:29.623 WARN 11496 --- [nio-8080-exec-5]
> .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Failed to bind request
> element:
> org.springframework.web.method.annotation.MethodArgumentTypeMismatchException:
> Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
> 'java.time.LocalDate'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to
> convert from type [java.lang.String] to type
> [@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam
> @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat
> java.time.LocalDate] for value '2018-03-22'; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parse attempt failed for value
> [2018-03-22] "

The problem is obvious so I found the solution and I changed everything. My method:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "reports/daily", method = RequestMethod.GET, 
                consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String getDailyReport(@RequestParam ("start_date") 
                             @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) 
                             LocalDate startDate, 
                             @RequestParam("end_date") 
                             @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) 
                             LocalDate endDate) {
    double totalDistance = 0.0;
    double totalPrice = 0.0;
    List<Transit> transits = transitService.getTransits(startDate, endDate);
    for (Transit transit : transits) {
        if (transit.getDistance() != null && transit.getPrice() != null) {
            try {
                totalDistance = totalDistance + transit.getDistance();
                totalPrice = totalPrice + transit.getPrice();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.fillInStackTrace().getMessage();
            }
        }
    }
    return "Total distance " + totalDistance + ", total price: " + totalPrice;
}
```

For me everything seems fine, I also added needed dependecies to pom file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suspect the issue is here:

```
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
```

According to [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.ISO.html#DATE_TIME) `DATE_TIME` is for date and time:

> The most common ISO DateTime Format `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`, e.g. "2000-10-31T01:30:00.000-05:00".

Your parameter of `2018-03-22` doesn’t look this way. Instead use

```
@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)
```

> The most common ISO Date Format `yyyy-MM-dd`, e.g. "2000-10-31".

The same for `start_date` and `end_date`.